# How do I implement an URL link to an already existing button using JavaScript & HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this on a SharePoint page:

```
<a href="#top"

onmouseover="document.getElementById('myimage6').src='LOCATION OF BUTTON IMAGE';"
onmouseout="document.getElementById('myimage6').src='LOCATION OF BUTTON IMAGE';" >

    <img src="LOCATION OF BUTTON IMAGE" id="myimage6" />

</a>
```

This works fine for a mouse over button, but of course when I click on it, it doesn't do anything. Can someone alter the above to make the button go to google.com or something?

I apologise for perhaps not using the correct code blocking, but it's quite unclear to me. I have removed markdown around the a and /a at the start and end.

Thanks.

C

Answer (score 1):

```
href="#top"
```

needs to be

```
href="http://www.google.co.uk"
```

Comment: @Bongs I have no idea what you are talking about. This is 100% correct

Answer (score 0):

It's a hyperlink - you just put your desired target in the `href` attribute:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">I go to google</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

```
<a href="http://www.google.com"> GO TO GOOGLE </a>
```